# Why doesn't my checklist get sent as a POST

Tags: ajax, django

I have the following template, which my button is working to send my select options to a POST and then switch URLs.  However, I have a collection of check boxes the user selects and I want to capture the report_id of each check box.  I'm on the last step of the project for my class with very little direction and struggling to get this form to work as intended.

```
<form action = "{% url 'submitted' %}" form method = "POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p}}
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="accesslevel"><h3>Access Level</h3></label>

<select name ="accesslevelid" class="form-control my_select" id="accesslevelid">
        <option value=""> Please select your access level  </option>
        <option value="7"> Facility  </option>
        <option value="5"> Division  </option>
        <option value = "3"> Corporate  </option>
        <option value = "6"> Market  </option>
        <option value = "4"> Group  </option>
</select>

    </div>
    <div class="col">


      <label for="phi"><h3>PHI</h3></label>

      <select class="form-control my_select" id="phi" name = "phi" >
        <option value = ""> Please select if you need access to PHI data </option>
        <option value = "0"> No  </option>
        <option value = "1"> Yes  </option>

      </select>

    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
</br>

</div>

</div>


<div class = "container">

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Available Application List</h1></br>
    </div>
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="col">

{% if fingrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Financial</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in fingrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
              </div>
              <div class="col">
{% if cagrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Care Assure</h3>
                <div class = "row">

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in cagrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
                </div>

              <div class = "row">
{% if pigrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Performance Improvement</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in pigrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class = "row">
{% if scgrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Supply Chain</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in scgrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class = "row">
{% if dssgrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>DSS Monitoring</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in dssgrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
              </div>

              <div class = "row">
{% if othgrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Other DSS Applications</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in othgrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
              </div>

            </div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="row">
{% if bhgrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Behavior Health / Rehab</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in bhgrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
{% if cegrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Clinical Excellence</h3>
                        <ul>
                        {% for app in cegrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="row">
{% if psggrouplist is not None %}
                <h3>Physician Service Group</h3>

                        <ul>
                        {% for app in psggrouplist %}
                        <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" >  {{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
{% endif %}
                </div>

              </div>


          </div class="row">
{% if showbutton is not None %}
            </br></br>


          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary my_select" type="submit">Request Access</button>
          <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
              $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var phi = $('#phi').val();
                  var accesslevelid = $('#accesslevelid').val();
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "{% url 'submitted' %}",
                      headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                      data: {
                          phi: phi,
                          accesslevelid: accesslevelid,
                        },
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function (result) {
                            if (result.is_success) {
                              document.location = "{% url 'submitted' %}"; //
                            }
                          },
                    });
                });
            });
          </script>
{% elif showbutton is None %}
You currently have acccess to all reports nothing is available to request.
{% endif %}

</form>
```

My view for the submitted request is defined below:

```
def submitted(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    checkedlist = request.POST.getlist('report_id')
    print (f"checkedlist on submitted:{checkedlist}")

    coid = User.objects.filter(coid = request.user.coid).filter(formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    facilitycfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 1).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
    divisioncfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 2).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)

    selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid')
    print (f"accesslevel:{selectedaccesslevel}")

    selectedphi = request.POST.get('phi')
    print (f"phi:{selectedphi}")

    for i in checkedlist:
        requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                      ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi , access_beg_date = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', access_end_date = '2017-01-31 00:00:00')
        requestsave.save()

    return JsonResponse({'is_success':True})
```

I'm trying to print the checklist list but it keeps showing up as an empty set in my console.  I'm not sure why, i've tried GET and POST.  Also, when using the JsonResponse to redirect my URL in the ajax it also sends a GET.  When I view my console it's displayed like the following:

```
[12/Dec/2017 14:37:16] "GET /account/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15804
checkedlist on submitted:[]
accesslevel:3
phi:1
[12/Dec/2017 14:37:21] "POST /account/submitted/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20
checkedlist on submitted:[]
accesslevel:None
phi:None
[12/Dec/2017 14:37:21] "GET /account/submitted/ HTTP/1.1" 200 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple details you may correct. The first would be: in your views.py insert the following conditional:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  alldata=request.POST
  # To get a specific attribute.
  data = [alldata.get('atribute_name,0)]
```

Second. As far as my own expririence. I prefer to deal with the action after the form submission in my views (server) not on the client. The reason is I have had the experience with certain browsers and in very particular ocasions. That before the form is submitted to my view the redirection occurrs. And no data is posted. So at the end of your view just implement the needed render or redirect function.

Finally you dont need the form word before the method in your HTML. Just leave it plainly like this:

```
<form action = "." method = "POST">
```

Comment: Hey Santiago, i actually had the if request.method == 'POST'  before my for loop, but i removed because with an empty set nothing gets wrote to the database.  Since i'm posting to a different URL i believe i need to keep my form action = the URL i want to post to.  I'm a beginner, so i could be incorrect there.  I've tried your changes and my list still doesn't post.

Comment: Why did you included {{ form.as_p}}. Do you have a forms.py defined?

Comment: Just realized I didn't market this as correct.  You were right in your answer.